# bad default python command

Tags: python, linux, centos

I just installed python2.6 parallel to my python2.4. I ran this command `ln -s /opt/python2.6/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6` and now when I type `python` i get this error:

```
/opt/python2.6/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can type /usr/bin/python2.4 and the old python loads up fine. How do I restore the command "python" back to the old python in /usr/bin/python2.4

Right now my server wont deliver web pages because of this.

Comment: What is the output from `locate libpython2.6.so`?

Comment: it doesnt output anything, jumps to next line

Comment: I fixed the path but my website is still down. I followed this tutorial to install parallel pythons http://www.venkysblog.com/install-python264-modwsgi-and-django-on-cento

Comment: This is a web server configuration issue and should therefore be on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your PATH variable. Fix the path in there.

Comment: I looked in my .bash_profile and there is nothing set in there

Comment: Maybe [this](http://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/setting-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-linuxunixosx/) will help you...